# SqlBulkCopy and StreamReader handling Large CSV with Quotes for text qualifier

Tags: c#, sql-server

I have a 400mb `.CSV` and wrote a routine to `SqlBulkCopy` the text records into SQL Server 2015. I have not found a way with `Split()` or the `StreamReader` to tell them that my `.CSV` has quotes for text qualifiers. Many records have commas in field content like a company name with a comma in it like "Acme Brick, Inc."

As a result of not telling the `Split` or the `StreamReader` I have quotes for text qualifiers (all fields are string type), the split is not able to discern that the comma in the field content is not intended to be a delimiter.

I want to load the large `.csv` into SQL Server via a C# console program per a requirement. Research indicates I could invoke a **VB Text field parser** and set the attributes to understand quotes are used as a text qualifier in the csv text records and comma outside the quotes is a delimiter.

```
parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
parser.SetDelimiters(",");
```

Research also indicated that the VB text parser method was quite a bit slower that the C# Split and could not handle large files well. I read this I believe on openstack.

So for a high performance large csv file processing routine to load the records into SQL Server programmatically in c# it would be great if I could set an attribute or `Split` for the `StreamReader` that would set them to handle quotes as  text delimiters in the case. Could I tell the split() something like

```
reader.ReadLine().Split('",');
```

where I tell it a quote and a comma together is really the delimiter. I presume I would need to escape the quote ...Split('/",'). Doubt that will pass syntax rules but just thinking wouldn't that be nice to be able to set the split to deal with the quotes as a text delimiter, so my field content with a comma in it would not throw the program off.

Is there such a thing? If not, what would be the best approach to dealing with these records in the large csv. I have attached my code and I get an errors on the first record where a comma is in the field content indicating the number of columns  does not match the destination.

```
    using System;
    using System.Collections.Generic;
    using System.Linq;
    using System.Text;
    using System.Threading.Tasks;
    using System.Data;
    using System.Data.SqlClient;
    using System.IO;
    using Microsoft.VisualBasic;

    namespace ConsoleApplication5
    {
        class Program
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch elapsed = new System.Diagnostics.Stopwatch();
                elapsed.Start(); Int64 rows = 0;

                using (SqlBulkCopy bulkcopy = new SqlBulkCopy("server=CHKNOWLAN-PC\\SQLEXPRESS;database=MarketData;trusted_connection=yes",
                    System.Data.SqlClient.SqlBulkCopyOptions.TableLock)
                {
                    DestinationTableName = "tblMarket",
                    BulkCopyTimeout = 0,
                    BatchSize = 100000
                })
                {
                    using (System.IO.StreamReader reader = new System.IO.StreamReader("C:\\ProgramData\\FMCSA_CENSUS1_2016May_1195.csv"))
                    {
                        using (DataTable datatable = new DataTable())
                        {
                            var columns = datatable.Columns;
                            columns.Add("DOT_NUMBER", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("LEGAL_NAME", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("DBA_NAME", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("CARRIER_OPERATION", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("HM_FLAG", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("PC_FLAG", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("PHY_STREET", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("PHY_CITY", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("PHY_STATE", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("PHY_ZIP", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("PHY_COUNTRY", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("MAILING_STREET", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("MAILING_CITY", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("MAILING_STATE", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("MAILING_ZIP", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("MAILING_COUNTRY", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("TELEPHONE", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("FAX", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("EMAIL_ADDRESS", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("MCS150_DATE", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("MCS150_MILEAGE", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("MCS150_MILEAGE_YEAR", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("ADD_DATE", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("OIC_STATE", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("NBR_POWER_UNIT", typeof(System.String));
                            columns.Add("DRIVER_TOTAL", typeof(System.String));

                            int batchsize = 0;

                            while (!reader.EndOfStream)
                            {

                                string[] line = reader.ReadLine().Split(',');
                                // Maybe use VB Text field parser here to parse
the line before adding to the datatable by setting the parser
 parser.HasFieldsEnclosedInQuotes = true;
 parser.SetDelimiters(",");
                                datatable.Rows.Add(line);
                                batchsize += 1;
                                if (batchsize == 100000)
                                {
                                    bulkcopy.WriteToServer(datatable);
                                    datatable.Rows.Clear();
                                    batchsize = 0;
                                    Console.WriteLine("Flushing 100,000 rows");
                                }
                                rows += 1;
                            }
                            bulkcopy.WriteToServer(datatable);
                            datatable.Rows.Clear();
                        }
                    }
                }
                elapsed.Stop();
                Console.WriteLine((rows + " records imported in " + elapsed.Elapsed.TotalSeconds + " seconds."));
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: There is **NO** SQL Server **2015** version - we have 2000, 2005, 2008, 2008 R2, 2012, 2014 and 2016 - which one do you *really* mean?

Comment: if their are commas in the fields is it aslo possible that the text qualifier (double quotes) are in the fields too?  If so is there an escape character or sequence?  Have you thought about using Sql-server directly instead of c# to do the import/insert.  you can still use your console program to control the flow.  But one way you could use builk insert to import http://blog.sqlauthority.com/2008/02/06/sql-server-import-csv-file-into-sql-server-using-bulk-insert-load-comma-delimited-file-into-sql-server/

Comment: You say all fields are strings.  Are all fields surrounded with quotes, or just the ones containing comms?

Comment: Can you not find and use a CSV library? You don't need to deal with any of this.

Comment: Options truly abound.  OleDB to import the file as typed data to a Datatable (your column defs appear to define some non-text items as string). CSVHelper can also import typed data, converting to a DataTable is pretty easy.

Comment: marc - Sql Server 2016 using VS2015; Matt - can you steer me a little bit. SSIS can turn into console program?; Johnathan - all fields are surrounded by quotes; usr - this sounds interesting can you steer me to any.;